# Model method showing error in magento custom model

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module in magento 1.9.And i am trying to load method in my model to controller.But it showing following error.
Fatal error: Call to a member function testing() on a non-object.
I loaded model in config.xml file as follows.

```
<models>
    <sim_categorynewsletter>
        <class>Sim_Categorynewsletter_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>newsletter_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </sim_categorynewsletter>
    <newsletter_mysql4>
        <class>Sim_Categorynewsletter_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <newsletter>
                <table>sim_categorynewsletter</table>
            </newsletter>
        </entities>
    </newsletter_mysql4>
  </models>
```

And this is my model class,newsletter.php

```
<?php
class Sim_Categorynewsletter_Model_Newsletter extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
     protected function _construct(){

       $this->_init("categorynewsletter/newsletter");
    }
    public function testing(){
        echo "inside testing method";
    }
}
```

This is my comtroller,IndexController.php.Here i am trying to load the method in models.But its showing error.

```
<?php
class Sim_Categorynewsletter_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function createAction(){
            echo Mage::getModel('categorynewsletter/newsletter')->testing();
    }
}
```

Comment: please use `$this->_init("sim_categorynewsletter/newsletter");`

Comment: no...same error

Comment: try instantiating your model from separate file and echo it's class by get_class

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create the same scenario and found the error. 
Replace the below code from:

```
<sim_categorynewsletter>
    <class>Sim_Categorynewsletter_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>newsletter_mysql4</resourceModel>
</sim_categorynewsletter>
```

to:

```
<categorynewsletter>
    <class>Sim_Categorynewsletter_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>newsletter_mysql4</resourceModel>
</categorynewsletter>
```